# how to delete subscriber using SSJS in All Subscribers

Tags: delete, subscriber

We have written a script to delete mass subscribers from All Subscribers. The same script was working fine last month. But when we tried couple of days ago, its not working anymore. We also tried to delete a subscriber via API but still no luck. Just wondering if anyone has come across similar issue.

Our delete script is here:

```
<script runat="server">
 Platform.Load("Core","1.2");
 var  BlockedSubscrbers = DataExtension.Init("4DA9-9F7F-6CF8860D494E");
 var dataExtensionFields = BlockedSubscrbers.Rows.Retrieve(); 
 var dataExtensionFieldsLength = dataExtensionFields.length;
 if (dataExtensionFieldsLength > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < dataExtensionFieldsLength; i++) {
   var subObj = Subscriber.Init(dataExtensionFields[i].SubscriberKey);
   var status = subObj.Remove();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

In MobileConnect the Contact Deletion API function was disabled (confirmed by MC Support and SF executive) and it's very likely it may have been disabled in Email Studio as well.

You can write to support to have it enabled again, but bear in mind it's deemed as unstable and there may be some unexpected results with it.

Comment: @Vadiraj this code working properly for me

Comment: It appears that the script above still works and that delete API endpoints exist on the official documentation

Comment: Yes, because it was re-enabled in 2018 January release.

Comment: Nice!! Thanks for the update. Suppose they needed it for GDPR